# C programming Linked list for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, linked-list

Given the standard linked list where "apples" is the list with (->first and ->last properties), and an "apple" is an element of that list with a (->next property). How does this for loop work?

```
typedef struct
{
    list_element header;
    int value;

} apple;

int main()
{
    list apples;
    apple * a = (apple *) malloc(sizeof(apple));
    apple * b = (apple *) malloc(sizeof(apple));
    apple * c = (apple *) malloc(sizeof(apple));

    a->value = 1;
    b->value = 2;
    c->value = 3;

    list_init(&apples);

    list_push_back(&apples, &a->header);
    list_push_back(&apples, &b->header);
    list_push_back(&apples, &c->header);
```

> ```
>     for (a = (apple *) list_begin(&apples); a; a = (apple *) list_next(&a->header))
>     {
>         printf("%d\n", a->value);
>     }
> ```

How does this for loop work?? The list_begin function just returns the ->first of apples. The ;a; as the conditional statement is saying if not 0 then continue the for loop? and the last part is pointing a to its next element in the loop. So when the last value of the loop is a=0 is that what would terminate the for loop?

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. What is your problem? What makes you doubt your interpretation?

Comment: Yes... The second argument of the for is confusing, something like `a != NULL` would fit better

Comment: Awesome thanks guys. This was hanging me up becuase it was in some code, and I couldn't figure out why it would terminate. I wasn't sure if C terminated the for loop where the middle statement is "0"

Comment: In C, `0` is false, any other value is true. The loop repeats as long as the test is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for) will help you:

> ```
> for ( init_clause ; cond_expression ; iteration_expression ) loop_statement
> ```
>
> Explanation
>   Behaves as follows:
>   ...
>   **cond_expression is evaluated before the loop body. If the result of the expression is zero, the loop statement is exited immediately.**

In your case, the `cond_expression` is just `a` and when `a` is zero (or NULL in case of pointer), the loop exits.

Answer (score 4):

The `for` loop is for traversing from the first node to the last node (until) it finds `NULL` (its for traversing the entire Linked List)..

The first parameter: `a = (apple *) list_begin(&apples)` puts `a` at the beginning of that list.

The second parameter: `a` is a condition and it gets violated on reaching one past the last node as it will be `NULL`.

The thirst parameter: `a = (apple *) list_next(&a->header)` is for traversing down the list.